# WinGetPos returning negative coordinates

Tags: autohotkey

I am trying to get the position and size of windows. I am seeing however that I am getting -9 for both X and Y on any full screen windows.

```
WinGetTitle, WT, A
WinGet, WID, ID, A
WinGetPos, X, Y, Width, Height, %WT%
ListVars
WinWaitActive ahk_class AutoHotkey
ControlSetText Edit1, [Title]`r`n%WT%`r`n[ID]`r`n%WID%`r`n[Dimensions]`r`nX: %X%`r`nY: %Y%`r`nWidth: %Width%`r`nHeight: %Height%
WinWaitClose
```

Output of the above code is:

```
[Title]
Stuff.ahk - SciTE4AutoHotkey
[ID]
0x4e079a
[Dimensions]
X: -9
Y: -9
Width: 1938
Height: 1048
```

Is it just my resolution that is causing this? When I use a window spy I can clearly see that the top left corner of the window is at 0,0 absolute or 9,9 by window.

Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: This is actually an issue with the way Windows 10 handles window borders. [This thread](https://autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?t=17955) has some good info on it (if you can overlook the arguing), and suggests [WinGetPosEx](https://autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?t=3392) as a possible workaround.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Client area is -9 x y from the window area to reach 0x0 of your screen. This is just how it is.